# Is there any danger related to streaming data into a c++ exception class?

Tags: c++, exception

Please consider the following code:

```
throw my_exception() << "The error " << error_code << " happened because of " << reasons;
```

The supporting code would be something like:

```
class my_exception
{
   public:
      template <typename T>
      my_exception & operator << (const T & value)
      {
         // put the value somewhere
         return *this;
      }
      // etc.
};
```

Is there any reason that would make such `throw` dangerous, or simply inefficient compared to the alternative below?

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "The error " << error_code << " happened because of " << reasons;
throw my_exception(s.str());
```

Comment: That's almost exactly how the [boost exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html) library works, so no, probably not dangerous.

Comment: @MilesBudnek : Please consider making your comment a full answer. :-)

Comment: Throwing exceptions *is* inefficient. All major compilers heavily optimize against the throwing case. IIRC, it was MSVC which joined in on the others, and recent releases of all major compilers now use lookup tables to get rid of most runtime overhead for the non-throwing case. If you have to worry about the performance of building an exception, you are mostly using it wrong – for common failure modes (e.g. no data available when polling) or even for control flow (baaad!). In these cases, consider an `optional` or `variant` or something like Boost.Outcome.

Comment: @ArneVogel : Thanks for the input. . . Please note, though, that I was actually comparing one use of exceptions (with streaming enabled) with another use of exceptions (manually using stringstream). . . I was not comparing exceptions with alternative ways of warning about an error event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're constructing the exception object via several function calls (the `operator<<` overloads), all of which happen before the exception is thrown.  This is no different than normal program execution.

The only potential issue is you can get a different exception thrown if something in the building of the exception object throws (like if there isn't enough memory available to hold the built error string).

So there's nothing inherently dangerous about doing this.